# I'm doing a math puzzle but I wish it was a riddle... Do it for me?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

AbcDEfg + aBcdefg + ABcDEfg = 24

ABcdefG + aBCDEFg = 2

AbCDefg + aBCdefg + aBCdefg = 0

AbcdEFg + aBCDEfg = 9

ABCdefg * AbCdefg = 6

AbCdefg + aBcdefG + ABcDeFG * AbCdefg = ???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This is signed binary: a sign bit (1 for positive) and then a binary number, least significant bit first. Capital letters are 1 and lowercase are 0. Thus AbCdefg + aBcdefG + ABcDeFG * AbCdefg = 2 + -33 + 53 * 2 = 75.

The translation of all the other equations:

> 12 + -1 + 13 = 24 
>  33 + -31 = 2 
>  6 + -3 + -3 = 0 
>  24 + -15 = 9 
>  3 * 2 = 6

Comment: Sorry.  I just double and triple checked.  You should check your math.  And I shouldn't respond to answers as I roll out of bet in the morning.  I'll accept again once it's fixed.  Also, take a look at http://www.purplemath.com/modules/orderops.htm to help get the correct answer as I had intended.  I should have used bracketing to make it clearer though.

Comment: Oops; fixed. The way you presented it was fine - I wasn't having an order of operations problem, just an I-can't-add moment.

Comment: That's almost there but unless I'm mistaken - and someone correct me if I am - the equation should be solved as follows: AbCdefg + aBcdefG + (ABcDeFG * AbCdefg)

Comment: That is how I'm doing it. Do you agree with all the numbers I've translated?

Comment: So you did.  :)  and yes, the translations are fine.

Comment: So then this must mean that fiveapples == sixoranges, correct?